# Cucumber not outputting to the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I'm playing with cucumber but for some reason the features and scenarios are not being outputted to the console.

When I run

```
cucumber features
```

I get

```
Using the default profile...
....

1 scenario (1 passed)
4 steps (4 passed)
0m0.071s
```

So my tests have passed but I can't see my features or scenarios. Is there a command line flag or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `-f pretty` resp. `--format pretty`.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the html output too, especially when debugging my step definitions:

```
cucumber features -f html -o "path/to/some/file.html"
```